# Higher regularity of solution to parabolic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Consider the parabolic problem
$$\left\{\hspace{5pt}\begin{aligned}
&-\dfrac{\partial u }{\partial t} 
+a_{ij}\partial_{ij}u
+b_i \partial_i u 
+c u
= f(u)  & \hspace {10pt} &\text{for $(x,t) \in \Omega  \times (0,T]$}
;\\
&u(x,t) = g(x,t) & \hspace{10pt} &\text{for $(x,t) \in  \partial_p (\Omega  \times (0,T]) $.}
\end{aligned}\right.$$
$\partial_p$ denotes the parabolic boundary. Here we assume that $u$, $a_{ij}>0$, $b$ and $c$ are $C^{\alpha,\alpha/2}(\Omega  \times [0,T])$, while $f \in C^{2+ \alpha}(\Omega)$ and $g \in W^{2,1}_2(\Omega  \times [0,T]) \cap C^{\alpha,\alpha/2}(\Omega  \times [0,T])$ for some $\alpha$.

Now I have the existence of strong solution $u \in W^{2,1}_2(\Omega  \times [0,T]) \cap C^{\alpha,\alpha/2}(\Omega  \times [0,T])$. How can I prove that  it is actually a classical solution?

I am going to prove that $u$ has a higher regularity, say $W^{2k+2,k+1}_2$ for some $k$, then I can use embedding theorem to show that $u \in C^{2+\alpha,1+\alpha/2}\in (\Omega  \times (0,T])$ is classical. But I can not find any reference for higher regularity. Can I have a book or text for it? Or may be there is another way to establish this?

Comment: Finally get some insight from Theorem 1.19 (page 16) in Nonlinear second order parabolic equations, written by Wang, Mingxin. But there is no proof in the book, do you think it is reliable?